# Android dexdump not found under platform-tools

Tags: android, dex

I'm trying to run `dexdump` command.. in many old posts, it mentioned that it's under `sdk/platform-tools/` but I can't find it in my android sdk. Where is it now?

Comment: it should be under `sdk/build-tools/x.x.x/`

Comment: @NaviRamyle thanks dude. can you post the answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be under sdk/build-tools/x.x.x/